# Gsub fails the first time, works the next?

Tags: ruby, gsub

With the following uses of `gsub`, I expect `"No, but I heard it's short and soft."` to be placed between the blockquotes. The first time, it's empty. When I immediately run it again, it does it right.

```
clean_content = "[quote=&quot;PDrizzle&quot;:1g581fap]No, but I heard it's short and soft.[/quote:1g581fap]\r\n\r\nwith very few ascents\r\n\r\nheh"
clean_content.gsub(
  /\[quote(?:.*)\](.*?)\[\/quote(?:.*)\]/,
  "<blockquote>#{$1}</blockquote>"
)
# => "<blockquote></blockquote>\r\n\r\nwith very few ascents\r\n\r\nheh" 
clean_content.gsub(
  /\[quote(?:.*)\](.*?)\[\/quote(?:.*)\]/,
  "<blockquote>#{$1}</blockquote>"
)
# => "<blockquote>No, but I heard it's short and soft.</blockquote>\r\n\r\nwith very few ascents\r\n\r\nheh"
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gsub` expects backreferences in the replacement string to be formatted as `\\1` rather than `$1`. In your example, the string replacement happening the first time refers to a variable that is the empty string, and the second time it has been set by executing the first pattern match.

So you want:

```
clean_content.gsub(/\[quote(?:.*)\](.*?)\[\/quote(?:.*)\]/, "<blockquote>\\1</blockquote>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that evaluation of the arguments precede evaluation of the method that take them. First, you had `$1` = `""`, so your first instance of `gsub` is equivalent to

```
gsub(
   /\[quote(?:.*)\](.*?)\[\/quote(?:.*)\]/,
  "<blockquote></blockquote>"
)
```

which makes `$1` = `"No, but I heard it's short and soft."`, so your second instance of `gsub` is equivalent to

```
gsub(
   /\[quote(?:.*)\](.*?)\[\/quote(?:.*)\]/,
  "<blockquote>No, but I heard it's short and soft.</blockquote>"
)
```

When you do it the third time, you will again have

```
gsub(
   /\[quote(?:.*)\](.*?)\[\/quote(?:.*)\]/,
  "<blockquote></blockquote>"
)
```